# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ffmpeg' Open AI GYM

Tags: python, macos, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm new to Open Ai gym but I was trying to find a way to record each episodes of my agent's learning. I found the class that should do the job :

```
env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
rec = VideoRecorder(env, "recording.mp4")
```

But each time, I'm using :

```
rec.capture_frame()
```

I get the following error :

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ffmpeg' Open AI GYM
```

Would you guys happen to know what could be the problem?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Do you use windows or linux?

Comment: Hey PySeeker, I'm using Mac OS

Comment: Can you post the gym version as well as python version?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just found a way to make things work on Mac OS :

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

then in your terminal do

```
sudo  ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.avi
```

It did the trick for me

Comment: The sudo gives administrator permissions to your command, this is probably why it fixed the 'Permission denied' aspect of the error.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right plus the brew install ffmpeg because it wasn't there apparently

Comment: If you are using sudo, you aren't fixing the problem, you're just ignoring it.  Likely you've got a misalignment between the owner of ffmpeg and the user who is running the function. By changing either the owner or the permissions of ffmpeg, you'll fix the issue and not need to use sudo.